# How I can load self.navigationController before `viewDidLoad` called

Tags: swift, mvvm, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, lifecycle

I want to do some stuff before the view controller calls **viewDidLoad**. I call **loadViewIfNeeded()** but **self.navigationController** is still nil. How can I load it?

#### AppDelegate.swift

```
func someMethod() {
    var viewController = Storyboard.instantiate()
    let viewModel = SomeViewModel()
    vc.bind(to: viewModel)
}
```

#### BindableType.swift

```
protocol BindableType {
    associatedtype ViewModelType

    var viewModel: ViewModelType! { get set }

    func bindViewModel()
}

extension BindableType where Self: UIViewController {
    mutating func bind(to model: Self.ViewModelType) {
        viewModel = model
        loadViewIfNeeded()

        // PROBLEM HERE: navigationController is nil, but view have been loaded
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        navigationController?.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .automatic

        bindViewModel()
    }
}
```

#### SomeViewController.swift

```
class SomeViewController: BindableType {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        // navigationController?.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .automatic
    }

    func bindViewModel() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I must put the line with pushing controller above **viewController.bind(to: viewModel)**

```
self.navigationViewController.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
viewController.bind(to: viewModel)
```